# CCCrypt Crash (EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, cryptography, exc-bad-access

I am trying to decode some data however when the data is larger than 520,000 (bytes? It's `[data length]`) my app will crash on debugger on the `CCCrypt` line, or if detached from debugger it just freezes and doesn't actually crash properly (Spinner keeps going round but app completely freezes).

This is my decrypt code:

```
char *key = ENCRYPTION_KEY;
NSUInteger dataLength = [data length];
uint8_t unencryptedData[dataLength + kCCKeySizeAES128];
size_t unencryptedLength;
CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionECBMode, key, kCCKeySizeAES128, NULL, [data bytes], dataLength, unencryptedData, dataLength, &unencryptedLength);
NSData *output = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:unencryptedData length:unencryptedLength];

return output;
```

EDIT ----------

Following Hejazi's answer below, I now have this, but it still doesn't work :(

```
- (NSData *)decodeSnapDataInBackground:(NSData *)data
{
    char *key = ENCRYPTION_KEY;
    NSUInteger dataLength = [data length];
    uint8_t unencryptedData[dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128];
    size_t unencryptedLength;
    size_t unencryptedDataLength = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionECBMode, key, kCCKeySizeAES128, NULL, [data bytes], dataLength, unencryptedData, unencryptedDataLength, &unencryptedLength);
    NSData *output = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:unencryptedData length:unencryptedLength];

    return output;
}
```

EDIT 2 -----

It seems this problem occurs when I perform the decoding on a background thread.
I was using this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
```

When I removed it, it now decodes large blocks of data fine.

Why would this be, and is there any way I can get this to work on a background thread?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/CCCryptor.3cc.html):

```
CCCrypt(CCOperation op, CCAlgorithm alg, CCOptions options,
     const void *key, size_t keyLength, const void *iv,
     const void *dataIn, size_t dataInLength, void *dataOut,
     size_t dataOutAvailable, size_t *dataOutMoved);
```

The second last parameter `dataOutAvailable` should be the length of the previous parameter, which should be equal to the input size plus the size of one block.

> For stream ciphers, the output size is
>        always equal to the input size, and CCCryptorFinal() never produces any
>        data. For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
>        equal to the input size plus the size of one block.

So, in your case, you should define `unencryptedData` like the following:

```
uint8_t unencryptedData[dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128];
/// kCCBlockSizeAES128 instead of kCCKeySizeAES128
```

And pass the length of `unencryptedData` array instead of the length of input data:

```
size_t unencryptedDataLength = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionECBMode, key, 
        kCCKeySizeAES128, NULL, [data bytes], dataLength, 
       unencryptedData, unencryptedDataLength, &unencryptedLength);
```

And by the way, you can use [RNCryptor](https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor) library which is CCCryptor wrapper for iOS and Mac.

***Update***:

Try running all background decryption operations on a single serial dispatch queue.
To create a serial dispatch queue:

```
dispatch_queue_t decryptionQueue = dispatch_queue_create("DecryptionQueue", NULL);
```

And then use it instead of the global queue you were using:

```
dispatch_async(decryptionQueue, ^(void){
    ...
});
```

Make sure to use the same queue and not create a new one every time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however this still crashes at the same point with EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2. If I limit the data to 520000 it works fine.

Comment: Do you have the same problem with RNCryptor? And also it's better to add a screenshot to the call stack when the app crashes.

Comment: I've changed KeySize to BlockSize but still the same :( Looking at RNCryptor, it seems it's only good for decrypting it's own encrypted data. I am not doing the encrypting in this case.

Comment: When you were decoding in a background thread, were you doing more than one decoding operation at the same time? It could be that CCCrypt isn't thread safe.

Comment: If you can add a screenshot for Xcode when it crashes it'll be helpful I think.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I do more than one at a time however it's only ever the ones above 520,000 bytes that cause issue. I think I may just leave it as it is now as it works and doesn't seem to slow anything down as the largest file is only around 5MB. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Still the same I'm afraid.